# Is IP Checksum checked at every router in the path?

Tags: networking, ip

IP checksum has to definitely checked at the destination. But is the checksum verified by each and every router it passes through??

And does the router in the middle of the path drop the packed if it finds the checksum is incorrect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [RFC 791](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791.txt) says:

> If the header checksum fails, the internet datagram is discarded at
>   once by the entity which detects the error.

and later:

```
Header Checksum:  16 bits

    A checksum on the header only.  Since some header fields change
    (e.g., time to live), this is recomputed and verified at each point
    that the internet header is processed.
```

So, it is a must to check at any entity of network layer (layer 3) the `IP header checksum` before taking any action on a received packet.

Comment: Thanks thats a perfect answer!! And with the references.